# Is L&U site’s meta a good place for listing advanced language resources?

Tags: discussion

On Russian Language & Usage site a meta-question was asked about [listing big names in Russian linguistics and philology](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/300/69) accompanied by links to their insightful articles about finer points of the language. Some of us think that this could be useful as a sort of FAQ for many users (to which we could also link in answers or comments), plus it could be search engine entry point for the site.

So, my questions are as follows:

1. Would the Meta site be a good place for such community-wiki? Are there precedents on other sites? In general, from the purist standpoint, is Meta a good fit for such type of resource? That is, is Meta only the support for its site, or also a “meta” for the subject of the site itself?
2. We already have [Resources for learning Russian](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/833/resources-for-learning-russian) wiki-FAQ. Would more advanced topics, such as the list in question here, or academic resources, such as [my question there](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/290/69) be okay on the main site, or it should be on Meta, or nowhere at all?

I am ambiguous about Meta, because I am not sure if it is a good fit at all (pending last question in the forst part), and for practical reasons as not a lot of users ever visit it.

Comment: Meta sites are for discussing their main site, not its subject.

Answer (score 1):

I think the information in [Resources for learning Russian](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/833/resources-for-learning-russian) should be placed in the [resources tag wiki](https://russian.stackexchange.com/tags/resources/info) (currently non-existent), or in a similar tag wiki like [learning](https://russian.stackexchange.com/tags/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/info).  Once a list of books and resources question grows to a certain size, people tend to post duplicate answers and the post becomes a mess.  Add to that, these questions and answers tend to be extremely subjective, so they're not constructive to begin with.